# Trek T-900 Tandem rear hub

Tags: hub, mechanical, tandems

I have a Trek T-900 tandem that I bought used.  It's probably about 12 or 13 years old.

I'm having some rear hub issues with it, but I can't identify what hub it is.  Trek's website and other searches just say "Alloy Hub".  I don't even know for sure if the spacing is 145mm or not.

I'd like to identify the hub, because it needs a new cone.  If that's not possible, I'd like to verify the spacing (I don't have calipers) so I can have a new wheel built.

Comment: A ruler works for me

Comment: http://sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html - use a ruler and measure it, or just take it to the shop.

Comment: This might go without saying, but you'd be fine just taking the wheel in to the shop.  No reason to drag the whole bike in.

Comment: I'm still unable to identify the hub, but the spacing is 145mm. It appears to be a 135 hub with spacers on the non-drive side. I guess a new wheel build is in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've verified that the hub spacing is 145mm - standard for a tandem.  The hub on the bike is unmarked, unbranded, and Trek's website simply lists it as "alloy hub".  It appears to be a 135mm hub with a longer axle and spacers in place.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I actually have the same tandem bought from e-bay (UK) around a year ago a bit battered. I have replaced both front and back wheels with usual 26" Shimano Deore mountain bike wheels from my local bike shop. Replaced lots of other stuff as well.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). The OP is asking for specs on this bike. If you have that information, please edit it into your answer.